# EJS file not showing up correctly

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, web, ejs

I'm having problems while using 'list-group' class from bootstrap with ejs. I'm trying to make an array "nome_grupo" to be loaded on 'list-group-item'. The problem is that it only shows up like a normal list and not like it should as it is a 'list-group-item'.

[image: web page]

as you can see, the first list-group is not like the one below. (the one below is not getting info from an array)

Here's the code from the .ejs:

```
<div class="list-group" id="lista_grupos">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            Lista de Grupos
          </a>
             <% nome_grupo.forEach(function(nome_grupo) { %>
              <a href="pagGrupo.html" class="list-group-item"><%= nome_grupo %></a>
             <% }); %>

    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry, but I'm very new to all of this...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're trying to output a li into a div. You should use ul > li > a or div > a and not div > li > a.

Comment: The <li> tag is used in ordered lists(<ol>), unordered lists (<ul>), and in menu lists (<menu>)

Comment: I've tried that already and it's all still the same, I've edited the code above to div > a. Am I doing anything wrong?